# Why jQuery ID not worked with dropdown IN ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I use Ajax to populate a dropdown in PHP, but the ID I use in ajax is same as Jquery id. So the data does not come into the second dropdown. Here is my jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var n = jQuery.noConflict();
    n(function () {
        n("#country_id").selectbox();
    });
    n(function () {
        n("#country_id1").selectbox();
    });
    n(function () {
        n("#country_id2").selectbox();
    });

    n(function () {
        n("#country_id3").selectbox();
    });
</script>
```

And this is my ajax code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function get_stream(){
    var country_id=jQuery("#country_id").val();
    //alert(country_id);
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '<?php echo Router::url(array('controller'=>'Prep','action'=>'stream'));?>',
        data: {stream:country_id},
        success: function (data){
            //alert(data);
            jQuery('#country_id1').html(data);
        }
    });
  }
</script>
```

And this is my html

```
       <div class="selectbox">
            <select  name="data[Jobboard][City]" id="country_id1"       tabindex="1">
                <option>select City</option>
            </select>
       </div>
```

What do I have to do to get the data in the second dropdown?

Comment: @Satpal sir its not solve my issue.

Comment: I am no __sir__ just use first/full name

Comment: what did you get in `alert(country_id);` ??

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing
this

```
jQuery("#country_id").val();
```

to

```
$( "#country_id option:selected" ).text();
```

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

you should try this:
`$("#country_id").next('.sbHolder').find('.sbSelector').html('Spain')`